# What would be the symfony way of adding and registering vendor bundles as selectable options?

Tags: php, symfony

Im trying to implement a function that will allow a user to select from a list of widgets. These widget have classes behind them that will get and display data based on given options. What im wondering is what would be the symfony way to render this list?

Lets say i have a file structure like:

```
vendor/
    namespace/
        widget1/
            Namespace/
                Widget1/
                    Controler/
                    Form/
                    NamespaceWidget1.php
        widget2/
            Namespace/
                Widget2/
                    Controler/
                    Form/
                    NamespaceWidget2.php
```

Currently I have a bundle in my project that has an entity that keeps track of all the widgets and their classes. What im wondering is if that is the best way to do it or if i should be using the file system like composer does and create something like a widget.json that will store the same info as the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my thinking but...

If you have multiple items that have the same dependencies you could either combine them into one and make them a complete bundle or you could put the common dependencies in a common bundle and then build you specific widgets in child bundles like..

```
Blah
    Common
    Widget1 (References Common)
    Widget2 (References Common)
    ....
```

For your case, you could use a common bundle that used a service tag that would then be picked up by a compiler pass that would then only build available widget in to the "widget service" which you could reference in your. For example...

service.yml (or something)

```
bleh.something.i_have_no_imagination:
    class: %bleh.something.i_have_no_imagination.class%
    tags:
        - { name: bleh.something.tag_name }
```

bundle

```
class SmartCoverPolicyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new YourCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

compiler pass

```
class RegisterRuleCheckersPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('bleh.something.common_registry')) {
            return;
        }

        $registry = $container->getDefinition('bleh.something.common_registry');
        $checkers = array();

        $ids = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('bleh.something.tag_name');

        foreach ($ids as $id => $attributes) {
            $registry->addMethodCall('addWidget', array(new Reference($id)));
        }
    }
}
```

service

```
class Register
{
    private $widgets;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->widgets = new ArrayCollection;
    }

    public function addWidget($widget)
    {
        if (!$this->has->widgets($widget)) {
            $this->widgets->add($widget);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private hasWidget($widget)
    {
        return $this->widgets->has($widget);
    }

    public function getWidgets()
    {
        return $this->widgets;
    }
}
```

This way you could add as many widgets as you want without needing to touch the common bundle really.

Comment: I like this approach thank you for taking the time to share your thought on it!